# Connect from specific ip address in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, distributed-computing

I'm writing a distributed system and I want to test it on my machine. I created several ip addresses on the interface lo using `ip addr add ip_add dev lo`.
I have binded all servers to their specific addresses and now I want my servers to connect to each other such that each server would think that it connects from his own ip. But when I use `connect` I get connection from my `localhost`. How is it possible to connect from a specific ip address?

Comment: You'd probably be better off testing it with Virtualbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that calling bind() on my socket does all necessary work.